# Quantile Regression Median place within bounds

Tags: regression, quantile-regression

In quantile regression I understand that I am estimating prediction intervals with an upper and lower quantile and that the .5 is supposed to be the median. However I have encountered a situation where the .5 quantile is not directly between my .05 and .95 quantiles.

Is that suspect or should I always expect the .5 to be ‘exactly’ between two upper and lower quantiles that match (eg +/- .05)?

Comment: By *not directly between*, do you mean $\hat y_{0.50}\neq\frac{\hat y_{0.05}+\hat y_{0.95}}{2}$ where hats denote point predictions and subscripts denote quantiles?

Comment: Yes, your mathematical definition matches what I am trying to convey.

Comment: What do you think of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

By *not directly between*, do you mean $\hat y_{0.50}\neq\frac{\hat y_{0.05}+\hat y_{0.95}}{2}$ (where hats denote point predictions or end points of a prediction interval and subscripts denote quantiles)? If so, this is generally not a problem. For a symmetric distribution, you will have $y_{0.50}=\frac{y_{0.05}+y_{0.95}}{2}$, but for an asymmetric distribution, this need not be the case. Unless you somehow restrict your quantile regression model to produce fitted or predicted quantiles that are symmetric around the median, you may very well get asymmetric point predictions. This is one of the benefits of quantile regression; it will fit both symmetric and asymmetric distributions seamlessly.